# Can I use graph.h, dos.h, and bios.h in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, header-files

Is it possible to use the following headers in Visual C++:

- graph.h
- dos.h
- bios.h

Comment: those are not libraries but headers

Comment: @MeAI: To gain reputation, and make others to answer your question, accepts the good answers of your questions.

Comment: Why do you want to use those? What are you trying to do?

Comment: VS 1.51 was the last one that could still build DOS programs.  You'll have to break into a museum.  Like the Borland museum: http://edn.embarcadero.com/museum/

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, No way to use this in Visual C++,

In the Mean While , 
I would like you to focus on Open Watcom C++ cross-compiler (capable to create 16-bit codes in 32-bit environment). It's a free one, so try to use this

http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Detailed_Contents

May be it helps...

Answer (score 1):

`graph.h` and `bios.h` are old headers, used for 16-bit MS-DOS OS and are not provided with latest Microsoft compilers. Header `dos.h` is provided with VS2010, and is located here:

- ..\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\dos.h
- ..\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\dos.h

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use the following
>   headers in Visual C++:
>
> ```
> * graph.h
> * dos.h
> * bios.h
> ```

You *cannot use* **bios.h** and **graph.h**, but *you can use* **dos.h** by following line:

```
#include<dos>
```